# How can one prevent mysql insertion within a particular timestamp interval?

Tags: mysql, node.js, timestamp

I have a system whereby users can input data into a mysql table from many sites across the globe.

The data is posted via ajax to my table without issues. But, I would like to improve my insertion code to prevent insertion if the timestamp is within some interval. This would weed out duplicate rows in my table.

Before you get angry -> I do understand I can set a primary key to certain columns and prevent duplicate insertion.

In my use case, I need to allow duplications of the numeric data where it is truly duplicated values from a unique submission -> this is valid in my case. I would like to leverage the timestamp to weed out obvious double insertions where the variables were submitted by accident twice.

I have tried to disable the button for 1-2 seconds, but this hasn't solved the problem entirely.

If I have columns: `weight`, `height`, `country` and the timestamp, I'd like to somehow check if there is an insert within n sections of the timestamp, where the post includes data that matches these variables. This would tell me that there is an accidental duplication from a user and I shouldn't insert it into the database.

I'm not too familiar with MYSQL, so I was hoping to get some guidance here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions, depending on the specifics of your case:

- If you need to apply some rule that validates the new row using values inside the row itself a `CHECK` constraint will do. Consider, though, that MySQL enforces `CHECK` constraints starting in version 8.0.3 (if I remember well).
- If you want to enforce a rule in relation to other rows, you can serialize the insertions into a queue. The consumer of the queue will validate the insertions one by one and will accept or reject them. Consider that serialization is not a good option for massive level of insertions, since it produce a bottleneck (this may be your case since you say insertions from across the globe).
- Alternatively, you can use optimistic insertion, and always produce the insertion with an intermediate status "waiting for validation". Then other process(es) can validate the row. If all is good, then the row is approved; if not, then a compensation procedure is executed, in *a-la-microservice* way.

Which one is your case?

Comment: I think mine would be situation #1 above. I get about a dozen or so submissions each day, so not an overwhelming number. I want to validate the new row against any row with the same set of data AND a timestamp that is in close proximity to that matching row.

Comment: Then, it's case #2. You could use some app logic or a database trigger.